# Android multiple WebViews Issue: Not being able to load the first one until the rest have loaded

Tags: android, load, webview

I have an activity that stores 5 `WebViews` in a `ViewFlipper`. It only shows one at a time. In the onCreate() of my activity I'm loading the first WebView on my main thread and the others in a background thread.

What I was expecting was to see the `WebView` right away while the others were still loading. What I found is that the first `WebView` i perform a `loadData()` with finishes last. I found this by setting a `WebChromClient` and checking the `onProgressChanged()`. The first WebView always seems to load last.

I'm assuming the WebView.loadData() function works asynchronously, but I have no idea why the first one I load always finishes last, not ever 2nd, 3rd, 4th or 1st, but 5th, which is last in my case.

Does anyone know why?

Here's some example code:

Setting up my WebViews

```
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
        WebView tempWebView = new WebView(this);
        tempWebView.setWebChromeClient( new MyWebChromClient( i ) );
        mFlipper.addView(tempWebView);
}
( (WebView)mFlipper.getChildAt(0) ).loadData( content, "text/html", "UTF-8" );
// load the others now in a background thread...
```

Here's my WebChromClient

```
private class MyWebChromClient extends WebChromeClient{
    private int webViewId;
    public MyWebChromClient( int viewFlipperChildNum ){
        webViewId = viewFlipperChildNum;
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        if( newProgress == 100 )
            Log.i("ChromClient", "WebView Id: " + webViewId + "Progress changed: " + newProgress );

    };      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after poking around a bit I really never understood why the first WebView was getting loaded last, but I did come up with a solution for myself. What I did, is I loaded the first WebView that we be shown all alone. Then, in the onProgressChanged( WebView view, int newProgress) function i load the rest of the WebViews in the background.

Example code:

```
private class MyWebChromClient extends WebChromeClient{
private int webViewId;
public MyWebChromClient( int viewFlipperChildNum ){
    webViewId = viewFlipperChildNum;
}

public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
    if( newProgress == 100 ){
       //load other WebViews now that the first one is finished!
    }

};
```

}